# How can I have a main method and websockets

Tags: java, java-websocket

I am looking for more information that I cannot find in my searches of the web. I am most likely searching for the wrong thing and I hope someone can correct me.

I have implemented a client(javascript)-server(java) websocket application. I have the connections working for several clients and now I want to start with some initial data created from a main method. However, the main method I have in my java application is not linked to the websocket endpoint. So if I create object instances when I run the application I want that information to be sent to the connected clients outside of the closed loop of session actions.

What I am describing sounds impossible to but I am certain I am just not explaining it properly.

Conclusion:

When dealing with websockets, how can I have an OnServerStartup so to speak so that I can either load saved data or create initial data?

Background:

I have implemented an annotated server endpoint using javax.websocket.server. The history which due to going out of order may have caused my quandry is that I started with the java application first and then I wanted to have a client UI to add, edit, delete data. So I went with a javascript frontend communicating with my java app via websockets. Now my app cannot communicate with the websocket connections or at least I do not know how yet.

Ideally what I am trying to do is have the useractions come in over the websocket and then I want to put the actions into a queue that my application then processes. When complete it sends the resulting changes to the dataset to all active sessions. There is a big issue here because I want to initialize saved data before allowing the websocket connections. Also if I have a timed event I want to be able to send all the updates to the connected sessions.

Comment: [this here](https://github.com/TooTallNate/Java-WebSocket/blob/master/src/main/java/org/java_websocket/server/WebSocketServer.java) is your server implementation? You could actually write a websocket server application and do things from the actual main method right after you call the `start()` method (it's non-blocking and creates a thread) of the websocket part. Or you make a thread. Or maybe I'm not understanding where your problem lies. Please explain :)

Comment: I have implemented an annotated endpoint via the javax.websocket.server.ServerEndpoint along with a glassfish server. Maybe I have just implemented it wrong for the use case. I did take a look already at the example you linked to. It seemed too complex so I went with a simpler implementation. specifically [this](https://tyrus.java.net/documentation/1.12/user-guide.html#d0e440)

Comment: Ok, completely different framework / environment. You can ignore what I said. For that you're primarily in Glassfish application lifecycle, dependency management & event processing area I guess.

Comment: I think you just confirmed what I was thinking. I need to implement websocket endpoints from my application. Currently they must be implemented by glassfish because I am not doing anything in my code. I was worried that using glassfish was going to give me issues.

Comment: Now I'm even more confused. By "java application" and "glass fish" you mean you have an application on a JavaEE Glassfish application server (https://glassfish.java.net/) that also uses the `org.glassfish.tyrus` implementation of websockets and those two parts are not connected yet?

Comment: Well Tyrus is just a reference implementation. I use implemented annotated server endpoints based on that implementation. However, glassfish owns the ServerContainer ( just found out that this is what I need to access the session data ). What I need to do is launch my own websocket server [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33415121/using-java-websocket-api-implementation-without-a-web-server). It's a little more complicated but I can keep it all inside my java application that way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are three solutions. They might not help the original poster using Glassfish; I do not know. But they are answers to the posted question and might be of some use.

I use embedded Jetty for my server. (Meaning the server is created in my Java code, so I have access to everything.)

**Answer 1:** Have your websocket server endpoint listen to CDI events sent from your main thread. I have not done this, but I think it is a very clean concept.

**Answer 2:** Have your endpoint "register" itself with the main thread.

Create a static collection member in a core class:

```
public class Core()
...
    public static List<MyEndpoint> webSockets = new ArrayList<MyEndpoint>();
```

Endpoint adds self to collection:

```
@ServerEndpoint(value="/path/")
public class MyEndpoint
{
    @OnOpen
    public void onWebSocketConnect(javax.websocket.Session session)
    {
        synchronized(Core.webSockets)
        {
            Core.webSockets.add(this);
        }
        ...
    }
```

Back in Core you will iterate through `webSockets` to send messages. Synchronize the iteration, or better, copy `webSockets` and iterate throught the copy (standard synched collection practices). You will also need to handle removal from the List in @OnClose, and watch for closed sockets during the iteration.

Note the synchronizations might be done in other ways as you need: Collections.synchronizedList() or CopyOnWriteArrayList are useful in different situations.

**Answer 3:** Take control of constructing the endpoint instance. This is the most powerful of my choices, as you can construct it with data and external references.

My implementation is JSR-356 (and Jetty) based, but there are hooks in other frameworks, too. Always slightly complicated.

During server creation:

```
context = new ServletContextHandler(ServletContextHandler.SESSIONS);
// ... more server creation

ServerContainer wscontainer = WebSocketServerContainerInitializer.configureContext(context);

wscontainer.addEndpoint(ServerEndpointConfig.Builder.create(MyEndpoint.class, "/path/")
    .configurator(new MyConfigurator(aSocketManagerObject))
    .build());
```

Where:

```
public class MyConfigurator extends javax.websocket.server.ServerEndpointConfig.Configurator
{
    private final ManagerObject aSocketManagerObject;

    public EventsConfigurator(ManagerObject aSocketManagerObject)
    {
        this.aSocketManagerObject = aSocketManagerObject;
    }

    @Override
    public <T> T getEndpointInstance(Class<T> endpointClass) throws InstantiationException
    {
        return (T) new MyEndpoint(aSocketManagerObject); // This constructor to be added to your MyEndpoint class
    }
}
```

The endpoint now has a reference to `aSocketManagerObject` and can communicate with it freely to acquire data, register as listener, whatever.

Bhaskar S. provides a robust implementation of Answer 3 at [Introduction to WebSockets](https://www.polarsparc.com/xhtml/WebSockets-03.html)

**Edit:**

More info on the CDI approach is in question, [How to get an existing websocket instance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18481597/how-to-get-an-existing-websocket-instance).

And [Accessing HttpSession from HttpServletRequest in a Web Socket @ServerEndpoint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17936440/accessing-httpsession-from-httpservletrequest-in-a-web-socket-serverendpoint/17994303#17994303) includes a long discussion about instances of endpoints.

Comment: This is great stuff! I am still interested in a solution here so this is helpful. As time passes more and more documentation and solutions become available. Thanks for taking the time to put explicit examples as answers!